# How to do a git reset --hard using gitPython?

Tags: python, git, gitpython

Well the title is self explanatory. What will be the python code equivalent to running `git reset --hard` (on terminal) using **GitPython** module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I searched for `reset` in [the documentation](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/) and found [this](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=reset#git.index.base.IndexFile.reset):

> `class git.refs.head.HEAD(repo, path='HEAD')`
>
> `reset(commit='HEAD', index=True, working_tree=False, paths=None, **kwargs)`
>
> Reset our HEAD to the given commit optionally synchronizing the index and working tree. The reference we refer to will be set to commit as well.

Answer (score 30):

You can use:

```
repo = git.Repo('c:/SomeRepo')
repo.git.reset('--hard')
```

Or if you need to reset to a specific branch:

```
repo.git.reset('--hard','origin/master')
```

Or in my case, if you want to just hard update a repo to origin/master (warning, this will nuke your current changes):

```
# blast any current changes
repo.git.reset('--hard')
# ensure master is checked out
repo.heads.master.checkout()
# blast any changes there (only if it wasn't checked out)
repo.git.reset('--hard')
# remove any extra non-tracked files (.pyc, etc)
repo.git.clean('-xdf')
# pull in the changes from from the remote
repo.remotes.origin.pull()
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
repo = git.Repo('repo')
# ...
# Remove last commit
repo.head.reset('HEAD~1', index=True, working_tree=True)
```